# Passing a complex function variants as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, functor

Say I have the following template function:

```
template <class T>
void apply(const vector<complex<T> >& in, vector<T>& out, T (*f)(complex<T>))
{
    out.resize(in.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) out[i] = f(in[i]);
}
```

You can see, I just want to apply a function to a vector of complex data, and store the results into a vector of real data. I figure this should be good for a whole list of function: abs, norm, real, imag, etc.

My problem is, how do I pass a function in?

I have tried variants of `apply(in, out, abs)` supplying different templates to `abs` with no luck. I am pretty sure the problem stems from the functions for complex all being templates, but I am not sure how to pass it properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `std::abs` (from `<complex>`) takes the `std::complex<T>` parameter as a reference-to-const. Your function pointer only says by value, which causes the mismatch. The following code compiles just fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

template <class T>
void apply(const std::vector<std::complex<T> >& in, std::vector<T>& out,
           T (*f)(std::complex<T> const&))
{
    out.resize(in.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
      out[i] = f(in[i]);
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::complex<float> > vcomp;
  std::vector<float> vf;
  apply(vcomp, vf, &std::abs<float>);
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/eE71v)

A better idea, however, would be to simply take the function type as a template parameter:

```
template <class T, class F>
void apply(const std::vector<std::complex<T> >& in, std::vector<T>& out, F f)
{
    out.resize(in.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
      out[i] = f(in[i]);
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/70dNj)

In any case, you sometimes might need to disambiguate at the call site with a cast, if a function is templated *and* overloaded (I don't remember one off-hand from the `<complex>` functions, but you never know).

```
// taking std::abs as an example. It's not actually templated *and* overloaded
typedef float (*func_ptr)(std::complex<float> const&);
apply(vcomp, vf, (func_ptr)&std::abs<float>);
```

Comment: `pow` is templated *and* overloaded, but it always takes two arguments.

Comment: I was unaware that `abs` and other complex functions take a `const&`. That doesn't seem to documented consistently. All works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you do not even need to invent `apply`, as what you want can be done with `std::transform`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
  std::vector<std::complex<double> > complex_vec(10);
  std::vector<double> double_vec;
  double_vec.resize(complex_vec.size());
  std::transform(complex_vec.begin(), complex_vec.end(),
                 double_vec.begin(), std::abs<double>);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I realize, but there is a lot more to my real function, what was supplied was just a small example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @steveo225: Do you mean your `apply` function does a lot more, or the functions that you plan to use with `apply` do a lot more? If the second, quite likely you can still use `transform`.

Comment: My `apply` function does more than shown, just needed a simple example