# How to apply function to all elements in array (in C++ template class)

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a template class that stores an array of numbers and I want to apply existing (scalar) functions to every element. For example, if we assume my class is std::vector, then I want to be able to call (for example) the std::cos function on all elements.

Maybe a call would look like this:

```
std::vector<float> A(3, 0.1f);
std::vector<float> B = vector_function(std::cos, A);
```

**N.B. I must also handle std::complex<> types (for which the appropriate complex std::cos function is called).**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112866/passing-a-complex-function-variants-as-arguments) which suggests taking the function type as a template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
std::vector<T> vector_function(F func, std::vector<T> x)
```

However, I couldn't get this to work at all (maybe because functions like std::sin and std::cos are both templated and overloaded?).

I also tried using `std::transform`, but this quickly became very ugly. For non-complex types, I managed to get it working using a typedef:

```
std::vector<float> A(2, -1.23f);
typedef float (*func_ptr)(float);
std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), A.begin(), (func_ptr) std::abs);
```

However, attempting the same trick with std::complex<> types caused a run-time crash.

Is there a nice way to get this working? I have been stuck on this for ages.

Comment: How about simply `std::for_each`?

Comment: As to begin "ugly", if you're using C++ 11, the `std::transform` can be written using a lambda without the `typedef`:  http://ideone.com/stYywt

Comment: I looked up `std::for_each` and it seems to just call a function on each value... I can't see how to keep the result (maybe `std::transform` is preferable in this respect?). I haven't used lambda functions before. Is there a way to make this generic/templated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I still think you should use `std::transform`:

```
template <class OutputIter, class UnaryFunction>
void apply_pointwise(OutputIter first, OutputIter last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    std::transform(first, last, first, f);
}
```

This function works not only for `std::vector` types but indeed any container that has a `begin()` and `end()` member function, and it even works for C-style arrays with the help of the free functions `std::begin` and `std::end`. The unary function may be any free function, a functor object, a lambda expression or even member functions of a class.

As for the problem with `std::sin`, this free function is templated and so the compiler cannot know which template instantiation you need.

If you have access to C++11, then simply use a lambda expression:

```
std::vector<float> v;
// ...
apply_pointwise(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const float f)
{
    return std::sin(f);
});
```

This way, the compiler knows that it should substitute `T=float` as the template parameter.

If you can use C functions, you can also use the function `sinf`, which is not templated and takes a `float` as a parameter:

```
apply_pointwise(v.begin(), v.end(), sinf);
```

Comment: I just upgraded my compiler yesterday so I can use C++11. That lambda syntax looks pretty weird, so it will take me a while to figure out what is going on... but it sort of looks like I have to write the template type of `v` manually. What happens if the type of `v` changes? Can I get the function to figure this out automatically?

Comment: @Harry `That lambda syntax looks pretty weird`  Get used to it.  It is a major part of C++ 11.  Second, change the type of `v` to what other types?  Whatever it is, it has to satisfy the conditions that you've set -- you can't assume that you can write a function where `v` can be anything you want it to be.

Comment: I think what I mean is that, if `v` were just a scalar, then (regardless of its type) I could pass it in to `std::cos` and the appropriate function would always be called automatically. I guess I might be able to achieve the same for `std::vector`s by overloading every function individually, but not using one generic function...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this post by Richel Bilderbeek ([Math code snippet to make all elements in a container positive](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppMakeAbs.htm)) which shows you why abs won't work in transform like that. The reason it won't work is due the abs function structure (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/). You will see `abs` is not templated itself unlike some other functions (mostly binary functions) found in the `functional` library.
A solution available on Richel's website to show you how you would apply abs to say, a vector of integers.

Now if you wanted to apply abs to a container using transform, you should know that the transform function received a complex object and will not know how to apply abs to it. The easiest way to solve this is to simply write your own templated unary functions.

I have an example below where I apply abs to the real and imaginary parts of the complex object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
std::complex<T> abs(const std::complex<T> &in) {
  return std::complex<T>(std::abs(in.real()), std::abs(in.imag()));
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::complex<int>> v;
  std::complex<int> c(10,-6);
  v.push_back(c);
  std::complex<int> d(-5, 5);
  v.push_back(d);

  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), abs<int>);

  //Print out result
  for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

As you have mentioned, you wanted to do apply the abs from the `complex` library. To avoid the unspecified behaviour (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108587/why-does-abscomplexint-always-return-zero)) you would use the `double` typename for the complex objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::complex<double>> v;
  std::complex<double> c(3, 4);
  v.push_back(c);
  std::complex<double> d(-5, 5);
  v.push_back(d);

  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), std::abs<double>); //abs from <complex>

  //Print out result
  for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will read through that. But `abs()` is not defined this way for complex numbers. For a complex number z, abs(z) = sqrt(z.real()*z.real() + z.imag()*z.imag()). In this case, the return type should be non-complex. The C++ implementation is described at [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/abs/).

Comment: So, this still works if I change the function to std::cos. It also works if I keep the function as std::abs and change the input type to std::vector<double>. However, it does not work if I change both the function and the type. I get `error: cannot convert 'std::complex<double>' to 'double' in assignment`.

Comment: I don't understand, you changed function to std::cos and are using std::vector<std::complex<double>>? This works fine for me.

Comment: If you are talking about type of the complex objects then you must use either `float`, `double` or `long double` as the behaviour is otherwise unspecified. If you want to add in that functionality you will have to make your own templates function (like I did above for abs) and implement the correct functionality (abs(z) = sqrt(z.real()*z.real() + z.imag()*z.imag())) and return a complex<T> object as the answer. In the case of abs you could store the answer in the real part of the complex object as that is how its implemented.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a templated function where you create a complex<T> by casting a `complex<float|double|double long>` and then call the functions specified in the `complex` library. You would then have to convert the real and imag types back to the T typename. Ie, you have `complex<int>(1,1)`, you make a temp `complex<double>(1.0,1.0)`, call `std::abs` or `std::cos` on that and return `complex<int>(static_cast<int>(temp.real()), static_cast<int>(temp.imag()));`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use valarray instead of vector, then you can do like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main()
{
valarray<double> dva{0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0};

// scalar operation   
dva += 0.25; // add 0.25 to each element of valarray inplace

// applying trignometric function
// apply sin function to each element and returns new valarray   
valarray<double> dva2 = std::sin(0.7 * dva);

// apply custom function to each 
// element. returns new valarray   
valarray<double> dva3 = dva.apply([](double dval) {
return (dva * dva)/2;
});

return 0;
}
```