# Is there a standard way to apply an expression to multiple elements in an array, like an unrolled loop?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, loop-unrolling

I've been wondering if there is any standard in C++, that allows you to expand static expression, based on the arrays or some other predefined sets of data, to N rows of code with their internal data.

Example:
if there is a need to sum up 5 adjacent matrix cells I would write a function like this:

```cpp
int sumPlus(const vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int atX, int atY) {
    static const pair<int,int> positions[5] = {{0,0},{0,1},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}};

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < 5;++i) {
        sum += matrix[atY + positions[i].first][atX + positions[i].second];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

but as I know, it will be translated to code with jumps (jmp or jle instructions) which is slow code. So the question itself: is there any standard that will provide the syntax, like this:

```cpp
int sumPlus(const vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int atX, int atY) {
    expression_array pair<int,int> positions[5] = {{0,0},{0,1},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}};

    int sum = 0;
    expression<positions : position>(sum += matrix[atY + position.first][atX + position.second]);

    return sum;
}
```

which will be expanded later into this by the compiler:

```cpp
int sumPlus(const vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int atX, int atY) {
    int sum = 0;

    sum += matrix[atY + 0][atX + 0];
    sum += matrix[atY + 1][atX + 0];
    sum += matrix[atY + (-1)][atX + 0];
    sum += matrix[atY + 0][atX + 1];
    sum += matrix[atY + 0][atX + (-1)];

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: why do you think the last version should be faster than the first? Do you have any evidence to back that up?

Comment: Much worse offender here is the `std::vector<std::vector>`, which is likely to produce many cache misses due to non-contiguous memory storage.

Comment: guys, i am not asking about your precious opinion about usage of vectors in my example or improvments of compilers, i am asking about a standard or possibility to perform such extensions of code on compiler level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply function to all elements in array (in C++ template class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468693/how-to-apply-function-to-all-elements-in-array-in-c-template-class)

Comment: If you say "but as I know, it will be translated to code with jumps (jmp or jle instructions) which is slow code. " in the question, and tag the question like [compiler-optimization], *then you should expect that people will try to explain the real reason why the existing code is slow* - because it shows that your actual interest is in making the code run faster.

Comment: Yes, it is about optimization, but i am talking about the loop substituter, i am not currently asking about : "how should i create a matrix, without memory or performance loss". Could you guys get a point : if i am asking about one thing, that does not mean, that i created this question to hear something on other topic, these answers dont even include a piece of usefull information?

Comment: The discussion of `vector<vector<>>` being an anti-pattern for performance was in *comments* not *answers*, precisely because it's not what you directly asked about.  It's totally reasonable that people would want to point you in the right direction on that, and warn future readers that this isn't a good example for efficient code.  See [how to create a contiguous 2d array in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21943621) / [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687) , or more simply use manual 2D indexing on a `vector<int>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Loop unrolling compiler optimization

Both versions produce identical assembly (when made equivalent), see https://godbolt.org/z/7Kf59r6o8

The optimization that you're missing is called "loop unrolling". The compiler already fully or partially unrolls loops, meaning that code such as

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { /* do stuff */; }
```

... is automatically translated into

```cpp
/* do stuff where i = 0 */;
/* do stuff where i = 1 */;
/* do stuff where i = 2 */;
/* do stuff where i = 3 */;
/* do stuff where i = 4 */;
```

Of course, it only happens if the compiler deems this worth it, which depends on heuristics. Clang is somewhat more aggressive in loop unrolling than GCC.
Just let the compiler figure it out, or, if you have done profiling and can know that the compiler makes a bad decision, you can improve it by forcing loop unrolling:

```cpp
#pragma clang loop unroll_count(2)
```

Personally, I would have written

```cpp
// I have faith that this loop gets unrolled.
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i) {
    // I have faith that this loop gets unrolled too.
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j) {
        // I have faith that this if statement is optimized out.
        if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
            sum += matrix[atY + i][atX + j];
        }
    }
}
```

### If you insist ...

> ```cpp
> expression<positions : position>(sum += matrix[atY + position.first][atX + > position.second]);
> ```

To get something along these lines, you could create some monstrosity made of `std::index_sequence` and fold expressions, but it's not worth it here.
In the end, it would look something like

```cpp
int sum(const vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int atX, int atY) {
    static constexpr int positions[5][2] = {{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{-1,0},{0,-1}};

    return [atX, atY]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return (matrix[atY + position[I][0]][atX + position[I][1]] + ... + 0);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<I...>{});
}
```

Anyhow, don't do this.
It's a purely academic code sample.

Comment: Also, this monstrosity is likely to have an impact on compilation time and is less likely to be optimised well by compiler.